# Is using a shield rather then a mask effective with COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, face-mask-respirator

I am seeing more people wearing a shield rather then a mask in public. I read [this article](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23675/are-transparent-face-shields-without-masks-respirators-reasonably-effective-at) here that talked about a mask alone as protection. To summarize the answer it was maybe a shield alone offers some protection to the wearer of the shield. But did not discuss if a shield helped the person wearing the shield from spreading a disease like COVID-19.

So the question is does a shield help (to any significant degree) the wearer from spreading COVID-19 in the same way as a mask?

Just to be clear a shield is a clear plastic face shield and a mask is a mouth and nose covering that offers some respiratory filtration.

Comment: In an elevator for example. Coronaviruses are 65–125 nm in diameter - thus respiratory filtration would protect the wearer to a greater degree, a shield would do very little. A shield is good for direct breath protection - alongside wearing a mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some advantages of shields:

- Eyes are protected in comparison to masks (CDC considers this the main reason to wear a shield; source: https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/prevent-getting-sick/cloth-face-cover-guidance.html).
- Disinfection may be easier for reusable variants.

Some disadvantages of shields:

- There are varieties of shields that are very small, therefore they cover less of the face than masks.
- Such small masks possibly may be collecting pathogens by guiding them towards the face when worn wrongly.
- Lingering aerosol particles can be inhaled more easily 'sideways'.

Some advantages of masks:

- For a sideways seal the N95 type establishes a better seal than surgical masks.
- Easier to carry around in a bag.

Some disadvantages of masks:

- Subjectively people claim it to be harder to breathe or talk with.
- Disinfection for reusable masks may be more involved, if possible at all for some variants of masks.

A publication by JAMA compares masks versus shields (https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/fullarticle/2765525)

In this there are a few references of studies conducted before the COVID-19 outbreak that evaluates protection by either cloth masks or shields:

- Rengasamy  S, Eimer  B, Shaffer  RE.  Simple respiratory protection: evaluation of the filtration performance of cloth masks and common fabric materials against 20-1000 nm size particles.   Ann Occup Hyg. 2010;54(7):789-798. doi:10.1093/annhyg/meq044 
  Source: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20584862/
  Summary: Fabric materials against aerosols are higher than for N95 respirator filter media but were in the range found for some surgical masks.
- Lindsley  WG, Noti  JD, Blachere  FM, Szalajda  JV, Beezhold  DH.  Efficacy of face shields against cough aerosol droplets from a cough simulator.   J Occup Environ Hyg. 2014;11(8):509-518.
  Source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4734356/  
  Summary: Face shields are effective, but lingering aerosol particles can easily be inhaled.

The main difficulty in the comparison seems to be the variety of masks and shields in use, ranging from self made to factory produced from a variety of materials. Also how masks are worn and also the fact that people sometimes touch these protective devices with unwashed hands on the inside may be a factor reducing protection.

Various institutions, including the CDC (https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/prevent-getting-sick/cloth-face-cover-guidance.html) and John Hopkins Hospital (https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/conditions-and-diseases/coronavirus/coronavirus-face-masks-what-you-need-to-know), do not recommend choosing face shields over face masks, when possible.

It may be that the combination of masks and shields (either using both or a manufactured variant including both) is the best option aside of more advanced respiratory protection equipment. For very exposed medical workers the combination has been put down as mandatory, e. g. in situations where endotracheal intubation is carried out on a patient tested positive for COVID-19; some modifications to this are in use, e. g. safety goggles instead of face shields.